# bind HttpPostedFileBase between views

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to pass a HttpPostedFileBase file between views to populate a textbox type="file"?

I basically have an upload texbox that uploads a file to the server on ane page.

On the next page we can revise all the data submitted in the form, including the image. This page has a back button that need to pass all the data back to the original page, included the image.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible to provide the value of a file input box, either through javascript or at page creation on the server for security reasons.  So, no, you won't be able to do this.

Instead, after the file has been uploaded, just write the information you want displayed on the next page in a regular div tag.

Answer (score 0):

No.

Instead, you can store it somewhere on the server (eg, a temp directory, session state, or a database), and pass an identifier to the next step.

Comment: ok so if I go back a page I will have to uplaod the image again. is that right?

Comment: @user441365: If you go back to where?

Comment: I have a back button in my confirmation page to go back to the form page. this page passes the model back